# Is it a bad idea to mention professor's name in the SOP

Tags: statement-of-purpose

I am applying to several Ph.D. programs this year. I am not sure I want to work with this professor as I never know him before, but mentioning his name makes it seems that I have already done some research on the school that I apply. On the other hand, if the admission committee does not include this person, then they may feel offended.
Alternatively, I can also say that the school is particularly strong in the field I want to work in without mentioning any name.

Answer (score -1):

Given all you say, I'd suggest that you name a field, fairly narrowly, that you want to work in. If that is his field, then fine. But, you don't know him and don't have any idea whether you would work well together. Avoid the complication and the possible sense that you are gaming the system somehow.

If there is a seminar group in the chosen field, you could mention that you are interested in that group, rather than an individual.

It would be different if you had met and already expressed some mutual interest.